# how to make pip3 install faster for existing packages?

Tags: pip

Each time I run my automated script, I want to make sure a certain python package is installed. For example, I run

```
pip3 install --user pandas
```

multiple times.

The second and subsequent runs (when the package is already installed) takes surprisingly long, about 7.8 seconds.

How can I make this checking and doing nothing faster?

My pip3 version is 9.0.1.

Part of output (second run) is

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached ...
...
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, numpy, pytz, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.1 pandas-0.24.1 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 six-1.12.0
```